# Display line number in addition to characters in emacs ocaml error message

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

Right now I'm in Emacs tuareg mode and I'm getting this error message

```
             * * *             * * * * * *       * *           Characters 2686-2820:
```

But it's impossible to find where that's happening.

Here is my .emacs file-

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/tuareg-caml-mode")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/tuareg-2.0.4")
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.ml\\w?" . tuareg-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(autoload 'tuareg-mode "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t)
(autoload 'camldebug "camldebug" "Run the Caml debugger" t)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(require 'linum)             
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

Comment: Just for the record: `M-: (goto-char 2686)` would do it. But I understand the inconvenience. How do you get this error? I'm usually simply copying the definition into the toplevel to test it, at which point it would print the whole error message in the toplevel.

Comment: @wvxvw gave the answer for how to go to that buffer position. A shorter version is `M-g c 2686`.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about the same thing and suspected there must be some sort of convenient solution for us out there already. First, I found this:

http://www.ocamlpro.com/files/tuareg-mode.pdf

which contains all the relevant short-cuts for Tuareg mode. Second, from that cheat-sheet, "ctrl-c `" (control-c apostrophe) in the top-level takes you straight to the error at hand. (For me this seems to work better when I've entered a function into the toplevel instead of a full buffer).